# How to copy data from table to another and automatically change the values to match the other's data type msql

Tags: mysql

I want to copy data from table column to another and automatically change the values to match the other's data type.

That is; in one table, a column is "Gender" and the values are Male & Female for every row. Now, while transferring it to the other table, I want "Male" to change to "1", "Female" to "2". I can't do it manually cause it's a huge table.

Comment: Can you not do this with some kind of case statement in your insert?

Comment: I don't really know how to.

Comment: OK.  How are you currently performing the transfer from one table to another? If you could post the statement I can amend it and provide an answer / explanation for you.

Comment: INSERT INTO table2 (name, state, dob)
SELECT name, state, dob FROM table1

That's an excerpt of it.

These are for tables with matching data types.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information and SQL supplied, you would need to amend the statement as follows:

```
insert into table2 (
        name, state, dob, gender)
select 
    name, state, dob, 
    case gender 
        when 'Male' then 1
        when 'Female' then 2
     end 
from table1
```

Remember that `NULL` values will obviously be ignored.

[MySQL CASE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Since you will always only have one of two values in this query, you can also of course use the `IF` operator, depending of course on how you want to handle `NULL` values.

```
select name, state, dob, if(gender='Male',1,2)
from table1
```

or

```
select name, state, dob, if(gender='Male',1,if(gender='Female',2))
from table1
```